# How would a Laplace transform be useful in analyzing this circuit?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, math, laplace-transform

I'm expecting a midterm question about the circuit below that involves the equation t=RC and using a Laplace transform. We won't actually be using differential equations. Memorizing a certain equation is all we need, but we're not told what it is. I've found a lot of equations when looking up Laplace transforms. Which equations would be helpful for analyzing this circuit, and where in the circuit could they be applied?

[image]

Comment: So what good does it do you if we just tell you the answer?

Comment: @W5VO Moot question because we won't do it. :P

Comment: Find the laplace form and matrix of the electrical circuit given above, provided that the starting condition is 0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the Laplace transform in circuit analysis works just like normal complex analysis. You just plug \$s\$ instead of \$j\omega\$ everywhere.

[image: Laplace circuit analysis rules from Wikipedia]

The interesting part comes after you calculate one thing or another since you can use Laplace transfer function to [draw a Bode (frequency and phase response) plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bode_plot#Rules_for_hand-made_Bode_plot) or to [calculate the circuit's response to any stimulus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Example_3:_Method_of_partial_fraction_expansion).

Comment: Why are those voltage/current sources there? That makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Jason the voltage/current sources are in the s-Domain models because a capacitor/inductor can act like a time dependent voltage or current source. Also, each have a frequency dependent resistance (impedance), which is why the resistor is in the model.

Comment: @Jason They represent the current or voltage at t = 0 and are needed to account for the energy stored inside the reactive elements.